# How to bind a class object into grid view through a different class object?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, exception, .net-2.0

I have 2 classes:

```
public class clsShipper 
{
    public string ShipperName { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class clsJobInfo 
{
    public long JobID { get; set; }

    public clsShipper oShipper = new clsShipper();
}
```

My GridView is as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvJobCostList" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgvJobCostList_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRowCheck" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblJobID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipper">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblShipperName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ShipperName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am trying to bind the ShipperName property of Shipper Class through the JobInfo Class object. I tried below

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (oOutputJobInfo.Length < 1)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Error : No Data Found";
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        dgvJobCostList.DataSource = oOutputJobInfo;
        dgvJobCostList.DataBind();
        dgvJobCostList.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

But gives below error

> DataBinding: 'Nucleus.BOL.clsJobInfo' does not contain a property with the name 'ShipperName'.

Comment: also tried this 
**<asp:Label ID="lblShipperName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Shipper.ShipperName") %>'></asp:Label>** instead of **<asp:Label ID="lblShipperName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ShipperName") %>'></asp:Label>** but no luck

Comment: You should not name classes with prefix `cls`!

Comment: @abatishchev, yeh ! But this is the convention my office follows. Not able to change it. :(

Comment: @abatishchev - Right, because it breaks the compiler.  The developer can prefix with foo, bar, boo, cls, my or whatever as long as they can read it and it's the standard they have chosen for their team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the namespace like so:

```
<%@ Import namespace="MyNamespace.ToclsJobInfo" %>
```

And you might need the namespace to clsShipper if different than clsJobInfo

Then you can cast/unbox clsJobInfo and use the property oShipper

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shipper">    
  <ItemTemplate>    
    <asp:Label ID="lblShipperName" runat="server" Text='<%# ((clsJobInfo)Container.DataItem).oShipper.ShipperName %>' />    
  </ItemTemplate>  
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I have tried this **<asp:Label ID="lblShipperName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(((clsShipper)Container.DataItem).ShipperName) %>'></asp:Label>** but it gives this compile time error  **Error 5 The type or namespace name 'clsShipper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Also, I don't think you need DataBinder.Eval when unboxing.

Comment: @V.P.Verma - sorry, I had the class names backwards.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: finally this solved the problem **<asp:Label ID="lblShipperName" runat="server" Text='<%# ((clsJobInfo)Container.DataItem).oShipper.ShipperName %>'></asp:Label>**  Thanks to all of you :D The StackOverFlow guys rocks !!!